# From list to nested dictionary

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, dictionary

there are list :

> ```
> data = ['man', 'man1', 'man2']
> key = ['name', 'id', 'sal']
> man_res = ['Alexandra', 'RST01', '$34,000']
> man1_res = ['Santio', 'RST009', '$45,000']
> man2_res = ['Rumbalski', 'RST50', '$78,000']
> ```

the expected output will be nested output:

> ```
> Expected o/p:- {'man':{'name':'Alexandra', 'id':'RST01', 'sal':$34,000}, 
>                     'man1':{'name':'Santio', 'id':'RST009', 'sal':$45,000}, 
>                     'man2':{'name':'Rumbalski', 'id':'RST50', 'sal':$78,000}}
> ```

Comment: Why not use an object instead?

Answer (score 3):

Easy way would be using pandas dataframe

```py
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame([man_res, man1_res, man2_res], index=data, columns=key)
print(df)
df.to_dict(orient='index')
```

```
           name      id      sal
man   Alexandra   RST01  $34,000
man1     Santio  RST009  $45,000
man2  Rumbalski   RST50  $78,000
{'man': {'name': 'Alexandra', 'id': 'RST01', 'sal': '$34,000'},
 'man1': {'name': 'Santio', 'id': 'RST009', 'sal': '$45,000'},
 'man2': {'name': 'Rumbalski', 'id': 'RST50', 'sal': '$78,000'}}
```

Or you could manually merge them using `dict` + `zip`

```py
d = dict(zip(
    data, 
    (dict(zip(key, res)) for res in (man_res, man1_res, man2_res))
))
d
```

```
{'man': {'name': 'Alexandra', 'id': 'RST01', 'sal': '$34,000'},
 'man1': {'name': 'Santio', 'id': 'RST009', 'sal': '$45,000'},
 'man2': {'name': 'Rumbalski', 'id': 'RST50', 'sal': '$78,000'}}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
#save it in 2D array
all_man_res = []
all_man_res.append(man_res)
all_man_res.append(man1_res)
all_man_res.append(man2_res)
print(all_man_res)

#Add it into a dict output
output = {}
for i in range(len(l)):
  person = l[i]
  details = {}
  for j in range(len(key)):
    value = key[j]
    details[value] = all_man_res[i][j]
  output[person] = details
output
```

Answer (score 0):

The pandas dataframe answer provided by NoThInG makes the most intuitive sense. If you are looking to use only the built in python tools, you can do

```
info_list = [dict(zip(key,man) for man in (man_res, man1_res, man2_res)]
output = dict(zip(data,info_list))
```